# NSData dataWithContentsOfFile returns different results on device

Tags: ios, iphone, hash, md5, nsdata

I'm using `dataWithContentsOfFile` on a PNG image and the iOS Simulator returns a value that differs from an iOS Device. My device is a 64-bit iPad Air (iOS 8.3) and my simulator is set to iPad Retina iOS 8.3. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sourcePath];
    NSString *hash = [self md5Hash:data]

    // Results on device: 2D25F346396FB00BEB27754ED1B56310
    // Results on simulator: 55016FD1AB3DA0F882FEA85D5ABCA2ED
```

I tested my hash function with a string, and it works fine regardless of device. I'm not going to display the results of the dataWithContentsOfFile method, but I can assure you that they're different.

Update: Testing `dataWithContentsOfURL` works fine, example:

```
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    NSString *hash = [self md5Hash:data]

    // Results on device: 57E396BAEDFE1A034590339082B9ABCE
    // Results on simulator: 57E396BAEDFE1A034590339082B9ABCE
```

Comment: I'd say the difference of the MD5 is because of the different architectures using different number formats. Could it be that the resizable iPad runs in 32-bit? Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697361/md5-hash-calculates-differently-on-server

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I'm using the Retina iPad, which is 64-bit. I've tested the hash code against text strings and they give the same results on simulator vs device in my case.

Comment: I would guess that the file is different.

Comment: (Consider that when you ask for an image file, the file system will select one of several synonyms based on the display resolution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that it's Xcode applying PNGCrush to your image... so it is actually not the same file.

Comment: This is it, on device builds pngcrush manipulates the image. I had to set the pngcrush directive to NO for it to work correctly. The interesting thing is that for simulator builds, pngcrush is not applied to the images.